# "Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures" is giving me a bad day

Tags: f#

I'm working with an `extern` DLL that has a bunch of routines that return a `ReturnCode` enum, so I wrote the following helper function to log all the errors:

```
let mutable LastError = ReturnCode.OK
let mutable LastReturnCode = ReturnCode.OK
let mutable TotalErrors = 0

let Run (call: unit -> ReturnCode) =
  LastReturnCode <- call()
  if LastReturnCode <> ReturnCode.OK then
    LastError <- LastReturnCode
    TotalErrors <- TotalErrors + 1
```

Great, except some of the DLL's functions have `out` parameters.  So now when I do something like

```
let CreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle: int) =
  let mutable evfImageHandle = 0
  Run (fun () -> Extern.EdsCreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle, &evfImageHandle))
  evfImageHandle
```

the compiler gives me a "mutable variables cannot be captured by closures" error.  Is there anything I can do beyond inlining `Run` everywhere?  This worked fine in C#.

(Example extern declaration below)

```
[<DllImport(EDSDKPath)>]
extern ReturnCode EdsCreateEvfImageRef(int inStreamHandle, [<Out>] int& outEvfImageHandle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard solution is to use references - the code becomes

```
let CreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle: int) =
  let evfImageHandle = ref 0
  Run (fun () -> Extern.EdsCreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle, &(!evfImageHandle)))
  !evfImageHandle
```

However this won't work as the compiler requires `!evfImageHandle` to be mutable, which it isn't.

I think the real solution here is to change your `Run` function so that it does not take a closure, rather have it take just the  return value - which will at least have it work in this case.  Then the code becomes

```
let Run (call: ReturnCode) =
  LastReturnCode <- call
  if LastReturnCode <> ReturnCode.OK then
    LastError <- LastReturnCode
    TotalErrors <- TotalErrors + 1
```

and the code changes to

```
let CreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle: int) =
  let mutable evfImageHandle = 0
  Extern.EdsCreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle, &evfImageHandle)) |> Run
  evfImageHandle
```

Or the even more hackish solution.  Use the fact that array members are mutable and can be captured by closures to do

```
let CreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle: int) =
  let evfImageHandle =  [|0|]
  Run (fun () -> EdsCreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle, &(evfImageHandle.[0])) )
  evfImageHandle.[0]
```

Comment: Invalid mutation of a constant expression. Consider copying the expression to a mutable local, e.g. 'let mutable x = ...'.

Comment: @lobsterism - forgot to get rid of the mutable and an error with the return.  Should work correctly now

Comment: I think you forgot to get rid of the `&` as well?  But that still gives me *Type mismatch. Expecting a     byref<int> ref     but given a     int ref     The type 'byref<int>' does not match the type 'int'*

Comment: I added my extern declaration as an example.

Comment: @lobsterism - I can't think of a more elegant solution than either eliminating the closure or creating a dummy array to use as an argument.

Comment: Gah! Can't believe I never noticed I didn't even need the closure! Code reviews suck but are awesome sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

You should still be able to use the `ref` type, but you do not need to write the `&` symbol when passing the reference to the function - the compiler will do this automatically:

```
let CreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle: int) =
  let mutable evfImageHandle = ref 0
  Run (fun () -> Extern.EdsCreateEvfImageRef (streamHandle, evfImageHandle))
  !evfImageHandle
```

Comment: *Type mismatch. Expecting a byref<int> ref but given a int ref The type 'byref<int>' does not match the type 'int'*

Comment: This doesn't work for me in fsi for either F# 2.0 or 3.0 using the following extern definition `[<DllImport("")>]
extern int EdsCreateEvfImageRef(int inStreamHandle, [<Out>] int& outEvfImageHandle);` (same error as lobsterism)

Comment: Type directed conversions are applied only to type members and I suspect here Extern is a module, not type